# How do I use electrum on multiple computers?

Tags: electrum

I would like to use my electrum wallet on multiple computers. Is it just a matter of using my seed to recover the wallet on the other computer, or do I have to do something special to set it up?

Answer (score 8):

As you have suggested, all you need to do is to restore the wallet from your seed on each computer and you'll have all your Electrum instances synced.

Labels can also be exported and imported on each PC in order to avoid having to re-write them; or you can use the plugin LabElectrum (Label Sync) to store them in the cloud and update them at your convenience.

Transactions will remain synced as they are received from the network.

Imported keys are not derived from your seed, so you'll need to manually import them on each computer. Or if you have many imported keys you can copy the electrum.dat file to each computer you'll use.